# Merge Users from Prod to Staging/Dev

Tags: drush, database, users

I have users registering on my prod environment, but I also have accounts created internally on my staging environment. Is there a drush command similar to  sql-sync or Drupal module that will simply merge the user table without overwriting all users and credentials?

Answer (score 0):

go through the discussion on https://groups.drupal.org/node/177179. You will get to know the answer of your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import all users from Staging/Dev

Then updating its passwords through a sql, because feeds let you import password without encryption only **Take in mind that no hook will be fired by doing it this way**

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dvf7bfQgowQ) for instructions

Another approach would be a sql selecting all user from dev users table (without nid) and put them into prod users table, but im not quite sure because i just saw that nid field is not AI. **Take in mind that no hook will be fired by doing it this way**